# Retrofit how to add commas in params

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

The result that i want is this :

> http://192.168.100.140/fitbook/public/api/bookings_trainer/1?include=city,trainee,payment_type,

but whenever i try to send data, 
using my code :

```
final Call<BaseResponse<TrainerBookingInfo>> call = client.getTrainerBookings(SharePreferences.getUserId(context) ,"city,trainee,payment_type,");


@POST(GET_TRAINER_BOOKINGS )
Call<BaseResponse<TrainerBookingInfo>> getTrainerBookings(@Query("id") String id,
                                                          @Query("include") String include);
```

it becomes something like this :

```
http://192.168.100.140/fitbook/public/api/bookings_trainer?id=17&include=city%2Ctrainee%2Cpayment_type%2C
```

how can i remove the "id"

```
http://192.168.100.140/fitbook/public/api/bookings_trainer/1?include=city,trainee,payment_type,
```

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Comma is a special character, it needs to be encoded in UTF-8 to be accepted in a URL, you can find all the special chars here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp. So what you have is completely normal, you just need to decode the URL in your backend (usually REST frameworks do this for you automatically)

Comment: it is being URL encoded, if you paste your string into https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ and decode it will become the correct string.

Answer (score 4):

By default Retrofit URL encodes characters, which is very common in current networking applications. (`,` becomes `%2C`). You can disable URL encoding like the following:

```
@POST(GET_TRAINER_BOOKINGS )
Call<BaseResponse<TrainerBookingInfo>> getTrainerBookings(@Query("id") String id,
                                                      @Query("include", encoded = true) String include);
```

This will let Retrofit know to not use URL encoding.

See here: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/f0b441b89eaf69397b35ec72704ca1bc6a9ddd6a/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/http/Query.java

> Parameter names and values are URL encoded by default (Specify {@link
>   encoded() encoded=true}
>   to change this behavior).

Update for your second question:

```
String GET_TRAINER_BOOKINGS = "http://192.168.100.140/fitbook/public/api/bookings_trainer/{id}";

@POST(GET_TRAINER_BOOKINGS)
Call<BaseResponse<TrainerBookingInfo>> getTrainerBookings(@Path("id") String id, @Query("include", encoded = true) String include);
```

Read more here: https://square.github.io/retrofit/